# What's the relationship between chips, wafers, and dies in a computer?

Tags: integrated-circuit, computer-architecture

I have the following question:

> If your demand is 50,000 RedDragon chips per month and 25,000
> Phoenix chips per month, and your facility can fabricate 70 wafers a month, how
> many wafers should you make of each chip?

Note: info about the die and such where given before and we calculated the amount of dies per wafer in a previous question, profit for each chip was calculated as well.

What they did is divide 50,000 and 25,000 per the amount of dies per wafer and got the amount of wafers needed I don't understand why.
From my understanding is that every chip is made of a wafer which has a lot of dies, if that is case case why don't we have 1 wafer for each chip, what am I getting wrong? Would appreciate you explaining the general picture and relationship between these three.

Comment: A chip is (usually) 1 die (NOT wafer) in a package. Once you've made a wafer, you slice it up to extract all the dice on it. Now here's the part the question gets wrong. Before slicing, you test every die, and then only package the good ones. So you need to know the % yield, and make enough wafers to allow for the bad ones. Without a yield figure, all you can do is guess it's 100%, and run the risk of coming up short. If one chip = one wafer, that's called "Wafer Scale Integration" and is a real rarity (except maybe solar cells).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. One wafer - many dies. Image source: [Computer Business Review](https://www.cbronline.com/boardroom/amds-ceo-wafer-supply/).*

> From my understanding is that every chip is made of a wafer which has a lot of dies ...

No. Every chip is made from a die which is a small part of a large wafer.

[image: 2]

*Figure 1. An Intel 1702A EPROM, one of the earliest EPROM types, 256 by 8 bit. Here you can see the one die bonded to the lead frame of the "chip" package. Source: Wikipedia [EPROM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPROM).*

One wafer will make many dies. Generally one die will be used and packaged in each chip.

Answer (score 2):

Dies on produced on the wafer. We have 8-inch/12-inch/etc. wafers, but the die is just so tiny. After all processes are done, the wafer are cut, and they become separate dies. Dies that failed the test process are marked and filtered out.

One chip usually consists of one die. But if stacked die process (several dies put together in the z axis just like a stack) is used, there can be multiple dies encapsulated in one chip. Thus area is saved on PCB. These dies are connected by metal wires between their IOs. After assembly/packaging, they become the chip that end users use.